# How can I use a custom CombineFn with Combine.GroupedValues?

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I've written a CombineFn that has input `KV<String, TableRow>` and output `KV<String, Iterable<TableRow>>`. I'd like to use Combine.GroupedValues (or Combine.PerKey), and the source could would seem to suggest that this is possible, but I'm getting the following error:

```
Incorrect number of type arguments for generic method <K, V>groupedValues(SerializableFunction<Iterable<V>,V>) of type Combine; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <String, TableRow, Iterable<TableRow>>
```

We're using Beam v2.10. The context here is that we're applying a session window to a PCollection of `KV<String, TableRow>`, then using a `GroupByKey` to create a PCollection of `KV<String, Iterable<TableRow>>`. After this step, our CombineFn reduces each group to `KV<String, Iterable<TableRow>>`, the Iterable containing TableRows created based on the contents of the input.

The transform steps:

```java
public PCollection<KV<String, Iterable<TableRow>>> expand(PCollection<KV<String, TableRow>> rows) {

  // group by step
  PCollection<KV<String, Iterable<TableRow>>> groupedValues = rows.apply(
    "Group by Key",
    GroupByKey.<String, TableRow>Create()
  );

    // combine step
  PCollection<KV<String, Iterable<TableRow>>> combinedValues = groupedValues.apply(
    "Generate New Rows",
    // errors here
    // Incorrect number of type arguments for generic 
    // method <K, V>groupedValues(SerializableFunction<Iterable<V>,V>) 
    // of type Combine; it cannot be parameterized with arguments 
    // <String, TableRow, Iterable<TableRow>>
    Combine.<String, TableRow, Iterable<TableRow>>groupedValues(new CreateEvents())
  );


  return combinedValues;
}
```

Combine Function:

```java
private static class CreateEvents extends CombineFn<KV<String, TableRow>, CreateEvents.Accum, KV<String, Iterable<TableRow>>> {

  @DefaultCoder(AvroCoder.class)
  public static class Accum implements Serializable {
    Double startTime = 0.0;
    Double endTime = 0.0;
  }

  @Override
  public Accum createAccumulator() {
    return new Accum();
  }

  @Override
  public Accum addInput(Accum accumulator, KV<String, TableRow> input) {
    // the earliest and latest times in the set of table rows is set on the accumulator

    return accumulator;
  }

  @Override
  public Accum mergeAccumulators(Iterable<Accum> accumulators) {
    Accum merged = createAccumulator();
    for (Accum accumulator : accumulators) {
      // merge steps happen here to find the earliest and latest times
    }

    return merged;
  }

  @Override
  public KV<String, Iterable<TableRow>> extractOutput(Accum accumulator) {
    // this step will create two rows based on the start and end times found in this function
  }
}
```

I'm expecting the CombineFn to be compatible with Combine.GroupedValues as the documentation would seem to suggest. However, this is not the case. Combine.PerKey is another option, but we haven't found a way to use that as well with a CombineFn.

Relevant links:
[Documentation - Combine.GroupedValues](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.10.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Combine.GroupedValues.html)
[Documentation - Combine.PerKey](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.10.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Combine.PerKey.html)
[Documentation - Combine.CombineFn](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.10.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Combine.CombineFn.html)
[Source - Combine.GroupedValues](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/release-2.10.0/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Combine.java#L214)
[Source - Combine.PerKey](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/release-2.10.0/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Combine.java#L165)
[Source - Combine.CombineFn](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/release-2.10.0/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Combine.java#L330)

Answer (score 0):

Signature of `CreateEvents` seems to be a bit off. it should be `private static class CreateEvents extends CombineFn<TableRow, Accum, Iterable<TableRow>>` to be used along with `GroupBy`. Here the input is `TableRow` and output of combination is `Iterable<TableRow>`

Here is the complete code

```
public PCollection<KV<String, Iterable<TableRow>>> expand(PCollection<KV<String, TableRow>> rows) {

    // group by step
    PCollection<KV<String, Iterable<TableRow>>> groupedValues = rows.apply(
        "Group by Key",
        GroupByKey.<String, TableRow>create()
    );

    // combine step
    PCollection<KV<String, Iterable<TableRow>>> combinedValues = groupedValues.apply(
        "Generate New Rows",
        // errors here
        // Incorrect number of type arguments for generic
        // method <K, V>groupedValues(SerializableFunction<Iterable<V>,V>)
        // of type Combine; it cannot be parameterized with arguments
        // <String, TableRow, Iterable<TableRow>>
        Combine.<String, TableRow, Iterable<TableRow>>groupedValues(new CreateEvents())
    );


    return combinedValues;
  }

  private static class CreateEvents extends CombineFn<TableRow, Accum, Iterable<TableRow>> {

    @DefaultCoder(AvroCoder.class)
    public static class Accum implements Serializable {
      Double startTime = 0.0;
      Double endTime = 0.0;
    }

    @Override
    public Accum createAccumulator() {
      return new Accum();
    }

    @Override
    public Accum addInput(Accum accumulator, TableRow input) {
      // the earliest and latest times in the set of table rows is set on the accumulator

      return accumulator;
    }

    @Override
    public Accum mergeAccumulators(Iterable<Accum> accumulators) {
      Accum merged = createAccumulator();
      for (Accum accumulator : accumulators) {
        // merge steps happen here to find the earliest and latest times
      }

      return merged;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterable<TableRow> extractOutput(Accum accumulator) {
      // this step will create two rows based on the start and end times found in this function
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Alternatively, you can also use a more concise way to group and combine by using [Combine.perKey](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/9a23704186f6a918a88f4e7560a3019a765a74de/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Combine.java#L1410)

```
  public PCollection<KV<String, Iterable<TableRow>>> expand(PCollection<KV<String, TableRow>> rows) {
    // combine step
    return rows.apply(Combine.perKey(new CreateEvents()));
  }

  private static class CreateEvents extends CombineFn<TableRow, Accum, Iterable<TableRow>> {

    @DefaultCoder(AvroCoder.class)
    public static class Accum implements Serializable {
      Double startTime = 0.0;
      Double endTime = 0.0;
    }

    @Override
    public Accum createAccumulator() {
      return new Accum();
    }

    @Override
    public Accum addInput(Accum accumulator, TableRow input) {
      // the earliest and latest times in the set of table rows is set on the accumulator

      return accumulator;
    }

    @Override
    public Accum mergeAccumulators(Iterable<Accum> accumulators) {
      Accum merged = createAccumulator();
      for (Accum accumulator : accumulators) {
        // merge steps happen here to find the earliest and latest times
      }

      return merged;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterable<TableRow> extractOutput(Accum accumulator) {
      // this step will create two rows based on the start and end times found in this function
      return null;
    }
  }
```